# How to call MouseEvent using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

This is the piece of code I would like to call with Java reflection:

```
private void cardSlotMouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
  // Some stuff

 }
```

Here is the code in the class ATM that calls it:

```
  // cardSlot is a JPanel

  this.cardSlot.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            ATM.this.cardSlotMouseClicked(mouseEvent);
        }
    });
```

Here is my code:

```
    Class a = ATM.class;

    Method m = a.getDeclaredMethod("cardSlotMouseClicked", MouseEvent.class);


    m.setAccessible(true);

    Object o = a.newInstance();

    m.invoke(o, "?"); // What is the argument?
```

I tried MouseEvent.BUTTON1 but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need an object of type MouseEvent to pass to this invoke method. Either you can use a System Generated MouseEvent  (created by mouse clicks) or you can create a dummy mouse event by using any [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#MouseEvent(java.awt.Component,%20int,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) Constructor

In your case, you can call desired method with reflection like this:

```
this.cardSlot.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        Class a = ATM.class;

        Method m = a.getDeclaredMethod("cardSlotMouseClicked", MouseEvent.class);


        m.setAccessible(true);

       Object o = a.newInstance();

       m.invoke(o, mouseEvent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell the JPanel to do the action since the MouseAdapter is called by the JPanel?

Comment: Wherever you will add this Mouse Adapter it will be invoked as soon as Mouse is clicked on that component

Comment: I am trying to simulate a hack. Link to ATM:https://codepad.co/snippet/yjATRN3S, Card:https://codepad.co/snippet/Z0zZfNhW

Comment: Any hints to "withdraw" an unlimited amount of money would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is a separate question altogether. please raise a different question with problem statement and code snippet to reproduce your problem

Comment: Instead of calling your methods by reflection you can also look for the possibility to create static method and call them on your class